# Envio de SMS Android

Tags: java, android

Estou a desenvolver uma app em android para envio de SMSs automático.
Quando envio muitos SMSs por volta de 200 ao mesmo tempo o telemovel desliga e apresenta o seguinte erro no log:

> ***display event receiver pipe was closed or an error occurred.
>   events=0x9***

Se alguém souber como resolver agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, Tenta particionar o envio dividindo em etapas. Ex.: envia 50, aguarda 5 segundos envia mais 50 até finalizar o envio de todas. Tenho um app que envia um sms a cada 1 minuto depois de ativado e não tive nenhum problema desse. mais vale a pena tentar. falow, se der coloca o código ae.

Obs.: um consideração seria enviar uma a uma em um tipo For(xxxxxxx) , estou dizendo isso por que não se você esta testando enviar tudo ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Não posso espera por segundos porque as minhas mensagens sao agendas e inclui também os segundos logo se espera por 5 segundos perco as mensagens que estão agendadas neste intervalo de tempo.

Comment: vc envia tudo de uma vez só ?.

Comment: faço o select de todas as mensagens que estão na base de dados e envio tudo de uma vez

Comment: Cara pode ser isso, mesmo tentar particionar isso. e muito rapido

Comment: O problema é que as mensagens nem sempre  vêem todas juntas por exemplo posso enviar 50 mensagens uma em uma dependendo da data hora e segundo que esta na base de dados.